# Finding a submatrix such that its inverse has the least frobenius norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Let $A\in\Bbb{C}^{m\times n}$ be a complex $m\times n$ matrix such that $m>n$. We need to find the submatrix (by deleting rows) $B\in\Bbb{C}^{n\times n}$ of $A$ with the least $||B^{-1}||_{F}$.

I feel somehow we need to pick $n$ rows which are almost orthogonal to each other. Any ideas?

Comment: Orthogonality is not what you need. Take the identity matrix and multiply it by a very small scalar. Then inverse is going to be huge.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How should I use this identity matrix multiplied by a small scalar?

Comment: I mean the conjecture about "orthogonal rows give smaller norm for the inverse" is not true. E.g. $A=\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon & 0\\0 & 1\\ \epsilon^{-1} & 1\end{bmatrix}$, $\epsilon$ around zero, taking the orthogonal rows (1 and 2) result in very large norm for the inverse, compared to the choice of rows 2 and 3 (non-orthogonal).

Comment: @A.Γ. Great example.